# Linked list of linked lists

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list that will hold other int linked lists, I need to be able to access the int linked list from the main linked list.

My question is how do I points the nodes of the main linked list to hold the head of the int linked list?

I created a static list: `dlist<Node<int>& > _plist;`
I have a function: `insertToHead ( T const& dataToInsert);`
But from the class that uses the linked list I only have the pointer to the head , something of :`Node<T>*`. and it gives me an error when I try to pass the `Node<T>*` to a `T const&`.

this is the constructor of the class the uses linked list:

```
Set::Set(int numArray[], int size)
{

    dlist<Node<int> > _plist; //static main list
    dlist<int> _intList ; //int list
    dlist<int> list;     //int list

    int i;

    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
       list.insertInOrder(numArray[i]); //insert in to int list
    }

    this->_intList = list;

    this->_plist.insertToHead(  _intList.getHead()); //gives an error

};
```

Is this the right way of doing that link between the main list and int linked lists?

Comment: I dunno if you're doing this as an exercise, but maybe  `std::list< std::list<int> >` might suit your needs.

Comment: From your description it seems the `getHead()` function returns a pointer, but you need to insert a reference. One way to do that is to dereference the pointer: `_pList.insertToHead(*_intList.getHead())`. This would be syntactically correct, at least. (Whether it really works, depends on what `dlist` does exactly with the element you pass it).

Answer (score 0):

With standard containers you cannot point to the elements because the main design is that the elements are managed only by the container.

What you do is a container of containers, i.e. in your case a `dlist< dlist<int> >`.

In other more complex cases you are however out of luck with the standard library... for example if you want to have elements that are at the same time contained in two independent linked lists there is no solution with standard containers and you have to code the data structure yourself or you must accept to pay extra costs for some operations.